# How do I get the default user-agent string in an NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I would like to append text to the default user-agent header in an `NSURLConnection`. I know how to [change the user-agent of the NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection), but I don't see how to get the default user-agent. I tried the following:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSString *userAgent = [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
userAgent = [userAgent stringByAppendingString:extraUserAgentInfo];
[request addValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

This does not work because userAgent is coming back `nil` from the `valueForHTTPHeaderField:` call.

Comment: Have you tried "User_Agent" instead?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There's a blog entry [Changing the headers for UIWebKit HTTP requests](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/04/07/changing-the-headers-for-uiwebkit-http-requests/) from iCab. He suggest using a process call ["Method Swizzling”](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling) to get what you want.  But there is a rumor that [Method swizzling cause for 4.0 rejection](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/ea606b4114565e75?hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

Part of the default User-Agent is your AppName and Version:

My user agent is:

```
User-Agent  foo-bar/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0
```

`foo-bar` is the value of `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(__bridge NSString *) kCFBundleNameKey]`

and

`1.0` is the value of `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(__bridge NSString *) kCFBundleVersionKey]`