# Apache BrowserMatch iOS to disable keepalive. Matching all iOS version?

Tags: ios, apache, httpd.conf, keep-alive

Due to the NSURLRequest timeout issue in iOS 8 and above, I had to turn off keep alive in my apache server. I read about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25996971/3162662 on how to set the BrowserMatch and I did it like this in httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule setenvif_module>
  BrowserMatch "iOS 8\." nokeepalive
</IfModule>
```

But I wonder if this only applies to iOS 8? What about iOS 9? How can I match all requests from iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember how to resolve that? :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this table os Safari user agents](http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/operatingsystem51849/ios), it seems that you could target by device like this:

```
BrowserMatch "iPhone" nokeepalive #All iPhones
BrowserMatch "iPhone|iPad|iPod" nokeepalive #All iPhones, iPads and iPods
```

If you want to target a specific system version, I would go for something like that:

```
BrowserMatch "iPhone.*OS\s8" nokeepalive #All iPhones on iOS 8
BrowserMatch "iPhone.*(OS\s8|OS\s9)" nokeepalive #All iPhones on iOS 8
```

I've quickly checked Chrome and Firefox for iOS user agents and it looks like the same regex would work. Of course all this needs some testing.

Comment: thanks but I am making network request programatically using NSURLSession. I am guessing I should target "CFNetwork" ? according to here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18406586/3162662

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that you were doing your requests programmatically. I have checked on the logs of some apps we have and I see different user agents. I think that your best option may be to check your Apache's access logs to see what is used by you app.