# How do I make my UIWebView or NSURLConnection tell a website that it is a mobile browser?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, mobile-browser

I have a website that detects mobile browsers and loads a different page to said devices. However, when I load the page in the UIWebView in my iphone app, it loads the default page instead of the mobile page. How can I tell the site that I'm a mobile browser?

My site is an ASP.NET site, with the following C# code implemented in each PageName.aspx.cs file for mobile redirecting:

```
if(Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true")
{
     Response.Redirect("mResults.aspx");
}
else
{
     Response.Redirect("Results.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is change the `User-Agent` header for the request.  The technique for doing that can be found in this question: [Changing the userAgent of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection).

EDIT:

Actually, I think your problem is that you're checking if `Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"]` is equal to the `String` `"true"`.  This will never be the case.  It should be a boolean value.  If you replace your `if` condition with just `Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"]`, I think it might work.  Like this:

```
if(Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"])
{
     Response.Redirect("mResults.aspx");
}
else
{
     Response.Redirect("Results.aspx");
}
```

Documentation for this value is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice.aspx.

Comment: Well, the site does load its mobile pages for Safari on an iPhone. The problem is only occurring in my app. But I'll give that a shot when I get the chance.

Comment: OK - if it's working for Mobile Safari, then the User-Agent fix might work.  I haven't been able to find additional info on what User-Agents ASP.NET considers 'Mobile'.  I did find this, though, which may be helpful: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for something like that list, I was just setting the User-Agent to "Mobile" as a test run.