# iPhone User-Agent

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm getching content in a universal iOS app using:

```
NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: link ]
```

... does that send iPhone/iPad user's IP and User-Agent to the server from which its fetching content from?

I *need* it to send at least user-agent so I can detect whether its an iPhone or iPad and optimize the content accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to make sure that the devices is sending an user agent by manually specifying which one to use.

Modified quote from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533032/716216

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10";
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myWebSite.com/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]
                                    autorelease];
    [request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
}
```

**NOTE:** The sample user agent I've listed may be dated, and you MAY need to find a newer one.