# initWithContentsOfURL behavior

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my code, I load a URL (an aspx file) in a UIWebview. It loads and displays fine.

```
[webView loadRequest:requestObject];
```

I want to inspect the HTML content being loaded on the iPhone. When I display it in UIWebview using the following code, the UIWebview display format is broken, showing lines and tables in word-wrap format.

```
NSString *htmlContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:inputUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:&error];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];
```

What could cause the difference, when a file is opened using loadRequest versus loadHTMLString as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for anyone who may be interested:

```
    NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3"; // user agent for iPhone browser
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:inputUrl]; // ARC enabled
    [request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]; //setting user agent
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // ARC enabled
    NSURL *base = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mainwebsitehere"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:base];
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to loadHTMLString does not know what URL to use to resolve any relative URLs that are contained within the HTML. This should be passed in baseURL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried specifying the baseURL, but that did not make any difference. I wonder if the problem has something to do with this being an ASPX file (which is processed by the ASP web server, and it returns HTML to the client).

Comment: I have also noticed that the break in formatting is very similar to when I did not have the correct "UserAgent" specified for iPhone safari browser. As if, the web server is not processing the htmlContent for the correct web browser.

Comment: You could try setting a useragent using NSMutableURLRequest, there is an example here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection

Comment: Thank you combinatorial. Setting the User-Agent first in the request, and then sending the request via NSURLConnection worked. I converted the NSData returned into NSString and displayed it in WebView using loadHTMLString.