# Worklight Push: subscription issue on iOS devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, push

```
Worklight Enterprise version 6.0.0
```

I am adding `WL Push` feature into my app. Now, I am coming across a serious issue on `iPhone`. In the `"Push Notifications"` tab of `Worklight console`, the number of subscribed devices are not correct, such as:

```
Push app

1 subscribed users;
2 subscribed devices;

Apple

0 subscribed users;
0 subscribed devices;

Google

1 subscribed users;
1 subscribed devices;
```

This issue causes that when invoking `PushAdapter` to push messages the above user, there is `"null" exception`. It means that `ios` users will be not able to receive push notifications.

Any idea for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Find one row of strange data in WRKLGHT.notification_device table. Moreover, for USERAGENT information, I also checked the table of APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT in Raw data report database. The USERAGENT information are collected correctly.

[image]

Comment: iOS 7.1.2. I also tested several other iPhone devices with iOS 7.x.
All of them have this issue.

Comment: Is it native or hybrid?By any chance you set this user agent header in your app?

Comment: It is hybrid. Not update the user agent header in my app. BTW, I find one more strange phenomenon. It works well on my DEV environment (http), but not working on UAT environment (https and IMC). >.<

Comment: Could be that something in that environment strips away this information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team found the root cause. It is related to the content in the following link:

[Changing the userAgent of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection)

My app is hybrid one. However, on UAT, for iOS, my team invoked the native codes (Object-C) to send requests because of some reasons. By default, they don't send user-agent along with requests.

Thanks, jayakarthik and Idan.