# How to use different User-Agent in different iOS Webview request

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, user-agent

I know I can use the below code to change the default agent:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

but I want to request a different User-Agent for different requests. Examples: request 'www.google.com', use agent=‘google Agent’, request 'www.github.com', use agent='github Agent'.

I have tried the below way to set the 'User_Agent' in each request, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.amazon.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [requestObj setValue:@"Foobar/1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];

    // But the value is not "Foobar/1.0"
    NSString* secretAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"]; 
    NSLog(@"agent - %@", secretAgent); 

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

One more question:

It seems a change to the default agent only work change in 'AppDelegate' or 'initialize'. Am I right? Because I try to change in 'viewDidLoad' but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

- I observed that if you load any url in `webView` with a `user-agent` set
  to it. After some time you load the **different url** & **different user
  agent** but used the same allocated `WebView` instane.The web view will
  load the new url but can not set new `user-agent`. It just set old one
  that you have set before loading first time.
- You can not change untill you initiate new instanse of `UIWebview`(or
  we can say that user agent can be set once per session). So I coame to result that `user-agent` can be set only once.

> - What I did for this problem is, I allocated new instance when I want    set new user-agent.

Comment: You can probably use the delegate `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` to manually request each page instead. Just return `NO` and load it by hand after changing the header.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set it using JavaScript.

You have misspelled **User-Agent**. Use this minimal code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533032/1781918)

```
NSString* userAgent = @"My Cool User Agent";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whatsmyuseragent.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: i use your way to try, seems the User-Agent also can not to change.

Comment: After request finished, i use `NSLog(@"User Agent - %@", [self.protocolWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"]);` to check the webView, it also print out the default agent